# Simple script that replaces a variable by a path with awk

Tags: file, replace, sed, awk

I am working with the PBS queue on a server.
I want to submit several jobs automatically and 
therefore need to replace a variable with a path. 
Since it is not possible to get arguments into a 
running script running with the queue, I want to 
replace the shell variables that are normally used 
with hardcoded parameters.

What I need is:

```
#! /bin/sh
#PBS -N runme_$file
#PBS -o $file.out
#PBS -e $file..err
#PBS -q batch
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -m abe
#PBS -r n
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
#PBS -l walltime=24:00:00

/home/example/proggie script $file $parameter2
echo "DONE"
```

replacing $file with '/tmp/output', so it should be converted to:

```
#! /bin/sh
#PBS -N runme_/tmp/output
#PBS -o /tmp/output.out
#PBS -e /tmp/output.err
#PBS -q batch
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -m abe
#PBS -r n
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
#PBS -l walltime=24:00:00

/home/example/proggie script /tmp/output $parameter2
/home/example2/proggie2 /tmp/output
echo "DONE"
```

The PBS part is important because it hinders usage of parameters. 
So i cannot just use $1 and $2 and give the script the parameters
it needs via arguments. Instead i have to change the file via a 
substitution command, then i can submit it to the queuing system.
I still want to be able to use the script from the command line, 
for quick testing.

I tried already using sed, but the possibility of special characters
occurring in the file screws up everything. There has to be a better way.

Comment: Your problem is not yet clear.  Why do you echo but otherwise ignore `$1`?  Where would the value to be substituted for `$file` come from?  Where does the value of `$parameter2` come from?  Where is PBS run; it seems to be wholly tangential to the question?

Comment: i edited the question to be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed "s%\$file%$file%" script.in > script.out
```

Using `awk` (`gawk` or GNU Awk):

```
awk '{ gsub(/\$file/, file); print }' file="$file" script.in > script.out
```

In both examples, I assume that this editing context has the correct value for the file name in `$file`.  I'm also assuming that you don't have any other variables such as `$file1` or `$filename` in the script; if you do have such variables, the regular expressions have to be more complex.  I also assume in the `sed` example that you don't embed percent symbols in your file names.

Comment: the awk line did the trick. however the sed part breaks. anyway thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What if you specified $file as ${file}.  Then you should be able to use sed.  When you say "special characters" I assume you're referring to other $ signs.  At least that's the only thing I can see in what you posted.